# What's the difference between C-u C-u C-u <Command> and C-u 64 <Command>?

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, prefix-argument

In org-mode, `C-u C-u C-u Tab` expands all trees. When I wanted to check what it's bound to, I wasn't able to do that using `C-h k` as it quickly told me what `C-u` is bound to. From experiments, I know that pressing `C-u` `n` times sets the prefix argument to `4^n`. So why doesn't `C-u 6 4 Tab` do the same thing as `C-u C-u C-u Tab`?

Comment: The command in question receives and inspects the raw prefix argument. It does not look at the `prefix-numeric-value` of that raw prefix arg. See @Tyler's answer for more info.

Comment: I changed the title to something more general, as the issue applies to more situations than just org-mode, I hope you don't mind!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a subtle distinction between `C-u C-u C-u Tab` and `C-u 64 Tab`. When you use only the `C-u` key, without using digits (i.e., 64), what actually gets passed to the `org-cycle` function (which is what `Tab` calls here) is a list: `(64)`. If you use `C-u 64 Tab`, the argument passed to `org-cycle` is the integer `64`.

It's up to the author of a function to decide how they handle this difference. In the case of org-mode, at least in the case of `org-cycle`, the underlying code assumes that users will only use `C-u`. It does this in a `cond` statement, where the tests take the form `(equal arg '(64))`. This will only be true when you use pass a list, not when you pass an integer.

You can find a full explanation in the Elisp manual: [(elisp) Prefix Command Arguments](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Command-Arguments.html), and also [(elisp) Interactive Codes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Interactive.html#Using-Interactive).